# How to assign id.columns of a data.frame a specific date format (Xyyyymm) in R?

Tags: r

**Background:**

I am trying to filter the columns of a large data set based on a subset formula, the problem is, I am doing it with the id number of the column rather than the actual name of the column that is equal to a date (in this format: Xyyyymm) which is definitely causing me trouble when manipulating id.columns and the desired time frame.

**Small sample table code of the dataset:**

```
   company <- c("AML Steels Ltd.", "Information  Ltd.", "Enterprises Ltd.") 
   X200201 <- c("A","A","F")
   X200202 <- c("A","B","F")
   X200203 <- c("C","B","F")
   X200204 <- c("E","F","D")
   X200205 <- c("C","A","F")
   X200206 <- c("A","F","C")

    df <- data.frame(company, X200201, X200202, X200203, X200204, X200205, X200206, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

**Actual code used to filter with id.columns (example):**

```
df1=as.data.frame((subset(df, select = -(2:3))), stringAsFactors = F)
```

**Is there any solution to this kind of problem?**

Comment: `subset` filters rows not columns. Can't you just use a regular expression to match columns that you want to extract? For example something like this `df[, grep("(01$|02$|03$)", colnames(df))]`?

Comment: if you are not familiar with regular expressions, you can use `dplyr` with eg. `df %>% select(contains("200201")`

Comment: I am not really aware of this formula could you give me some insight on it, please @Stephan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subset` filters rows not columns.

To filter columns you could use a regular expression to match columns that you want to select.

For example to match columns whose names end in `01`, `02` or `03` you can do

```
df[, grep("(01$|02$|03$)", colnames(df))];
#  X200201 X200202 X200203
#1       A       A       C
#2       A       B       B
#3       F       F       F
```

Or you can define a function that converts column names to a date with `as.Date`, and then returns columns indices for columns falling within a certain date interval.

---

### Update

Let's define a function that let's you specify a `start` and `end` date in the form `%Y%m` based on which you select columns from `df`.

```
library(zoo);
sel.col <- function(start, end, df) {
    dates <- as.yearmon(sub("X", "", colnames(df)[-1]), "%Y%m");
    start <- as.yearmon(start, "%Y%m");
    end <- as.yearmon(end, "%Y%m");
    which(dates >= start & dates <= end) + 1;
}
```

The following code line selects columns with dates that lie within Jan 2002 and March 2002.

```
df[, sel.col("200201", "200203", df)]
#  X200201 X200202 X200203
#1       A       A       C
#2       A       B       B
#3       F       F       F
```

Comment: Imagine I am using a 15 years data set with monthly data (180 months).. Would I be able to choose for example 200401 to 200703?

Comment: You forgot the X in the dates? (it gives me error).. thanks by the way! And if I want it to transform the time frame into a data.frame? would it be possible?

Comment: @Robin_Hcp Not sure what you mean about the `X` in the dates. The code above works on the sample data you give without any errors. I'm also not sure what a "time frame" is; `df[, sel.col("200201", "200203", df)]` returns a `data.frame`.

Comment: Great @Robin_Hcp; glad it helped!